# Center map on specific marker and fitToBounds on other markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with few markers which one of them is "Major" and should be in the center of the map. What I want to achieve is

1. Have the "Major" marker at the center of the map.
2. Have all other markers visible at optimal zoom level.

Fittobounds will center the map not taking into consideration the "Major" marker. Is there anyway I can achieve both #1 and #2?

Answer (score 1):

1. add all the markers to an empty google.maps.LatLngBounds object with .extend
2. call google.maps.Map.fitBounds on the resulting bounds (will center and zoom the map to show all the markers)
3. once the bounds has changed (in the bounds_changed event listener), center the map on the "Major" marker
4. once the bounds has changed a second time (in the bounds_changed event listener), get the updated bounds of the viewport (google.maps.getBounds) (check to see if any of the markers moved off the visible map)
5. iterate through all your markers, if bounds.contains(markers[i].getPosition()) is false for any marker, decrease the bounds by 1 (zoom out once).

Comment: Tried that. There are few issues:

1. map.setCenter doesn't work if called from bounds_changed event hanlder.

2. bounds_changed event is being raised few times. I'm not sure on how to distinguish between this event which is called after fitBounds at the page load and any other thing that might cause the bounds to change, for example, user panning.

Comment: Please post the code where you "tried that". You need to build a state machine to deal with the multiple times that bounds_changed is called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply declare your new bounds object.

```
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Then for each marker, extend your bounds object:

```
bounds.extend(myLatLng);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

API: [google.maps.LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds)